# Regex to remove last word in String + additional characters

Tags: java, regex

I am getting a String from a server and I have to use a regular expression to parse it.

I know how I would do it using String functions (String.split and the likes), but not with regexes, which is in the homework requirements.

The Strings look like this:

```
12345 <RECTANGLE> 100 200 300 400 </RECTANGLE>
```

I have to use a regex to make that String become:

```
12345 RECTANGLE 100 200 300 400
```

So basically, I have to remove all the following characters: "<", ">" and "/". I also have to remove the last word, so I guess I don't even have to check for "/" since removing the last word would probably remove the slash as well.

Right now I have:

```
shapeString.replaceAll("[</>]", "");
```

And it removes the characters I don't need, but I don't know how to remove the last word.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add

```
str.replaceAll(" [^ ]+$", "")
```

to remove the last word and the space preceding it.

Here is [a link to ideone with a running example](http://ideone.com/qOWl3).

Comment: @AdamSmith You can chain them together. Follow the link in the answer to see a running demo.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly! I didn't know about that regex to remove the last word. Also, I hadn't thought of using two replaceAll calls.

Comment: I used this in a loop, it caused an infinite loop if the string has a space at the end and did not remove anything, so if you trim it first it works fine.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `replaceAll` or alternatively, this:

```
shapeString = shapeString.substring(0, shapeString.lastIndexOf(' '));
```

for removing the last word.